# how to add footer Image to UITableView in RootViewController in splitViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, footer

I want to add footer Image at bottom of the TableView as we have the navigation bar image in SplitViewConroller but it does not get show it is showed when i scroll the table then it shows otherwise it does not show on screen here is the image i want same bar at bottom also which is in top in Table.

[image]

here is another image where when i scroll tableView then it shows image i want that without scroll it may show at bottom as top bar showing without scrolloing

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `UIImageView` with your image and add to `tableFooterView` like

```
UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
tableView.tableFooterView = imView;
```

Comment: have you seen both images and what i want when writing your code app crasheds

Comment: try the edited code, it works fine in my code.the function name imagenamed was spelled wrong. add this code snippet in viewDidLoad functio

Comment: add a navigation bar as subview of the view with the background image in the view setting frame as it should be displayed.Don't add it as subview of tableview.Then if you scroll, tableview will be scrolled and the navbar is fixed at the bottom